# Can Windows ACL emulate the sticky bit?

Tags: windows, permissions

Can windows ACLs be configured in a way that works like the linux sticky bit?
Concretely, I want to create a folder with ACLs that allow users to create arbitrary subfolders where no other user would have write access, just like /tmp works on Linux.

There is a partial answer burried in here:
[Is there a Windows equivalent of the Setuid?](https://superuser.com/questions/973349/is-there-a-windows-equivalent-of-the-setuid/973359#973359) , explaining how to set windows ACLs to get the equivalent of sticky bit for files, but does not mention if it is possible to have the equivalent of sticky for folders as well.

Another partial answer is available here: [Set permissions on NTFS folder to control permissions on contents of newly created subfolders](https://superuser.com/questions/1206111/set-permissions-on-ntfs-folder-to-control-permissions-on-contents-of-newly-creat) , but it seems the configuration does not allow the users to create arbitrary subfolders

Comment: sticky bit nolonger has an effect of files: the linked question is about setuid/gid bits.